Bootstrap 4 Navbar not working on mobile view
I'm having an issue in the mobile view of my chrome dev tools.  I've seen the issue on a friend's phone, but my phone works fine...
I have a bootstrap 4 navbar with dropdown menus, and the dropdown menus don't expand on the Chrome devtools mobile view.
The website is https://www.uvm.edu/femc/
Here is the code:
<nav id="toprightnav" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" role="navigation">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> 
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end ml-auto" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-items-end ml-auto d-lg-flex">
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data" class="headernavli nav-link" >Data</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/index#contribute">Contribute Data</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data">Find Data</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/products/collections">Collections</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/live">Live Meteorological Data</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data_rescue">Data Rescue</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/resources">Additional Data Resources</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/user_guides">User Guides</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item no-dropdown h-100">
                <a role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/monitoring" class="headernavli nav-link no-border" >Monitoring</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/products/tools_projects" class="headernavli nav-link" >Tools & Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/products/tools_projects">Tools & Projects</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/products/reports">Publications</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item no-dropdown h-100">
                <a role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/services" class="headernavli nav-link no-border" >Services</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/cooperative" class="headernavli nav-link" >Collaborate</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/cooperative/conference">Annual Meeting</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/emf/rfp">Ecosystem Monitoring Fund</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/cooperative/join">Join a project or state advisory committee</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about" class="headernavli nav-link" >About FEMC</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about">Overview</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/staff">Staff</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/strategic_plan">Strategic Plan</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/deij_initiatives">Our DEIJ Committment</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/work_with_us">Job Opportunities</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/contact">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </li>                        
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

I searched stackoverflow and it seems like something could be blocking the link?  But I looked in devtools and didn't see any divs blocking.  I'm not sure what else to try...

I see them expanding, but you have a link in the href, use # instead, otherwise you get redirected.


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
  <nav id="toprightnav" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md" role="navigation">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"> 
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end ml-auto" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-items-end ml-auto d-lg-flex">
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" class="headernavli nav-link" >Data</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/index#contribute">Contribute Data</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data">Find Data</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/products/collections">Collections</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/live">Live Meteorological Data</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data_rescue">Data Rescue</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/resources">Additional Data Resources</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/data/user_guides">User Guides</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item no-dropdown h-100">
                <a aria-expanded="false" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/monitoring" class="headernavli nav-link no-border" >Monitoring</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" class="headernavli nav-link" >Tools & Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/products/tools_projects">Tools & Projects</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/products/reports">Publications</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item no-dropdown h-100">
                <a href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/services" class="headernavli nav-link no-border" >Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" class="headernavli nav-link" >Collaborate</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/cooperative/conference">Annual Meeting</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/emf/rfp">Ecosystem Monitoring Fund</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/cooperative/join">Join a project or state advisory committee</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item h-100 dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="#" class="headernavli nav-link" >About FEMC</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about">Overview</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/staff">Staff</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/strategic_plan">Strategic Plan</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/deij_initiatives">Our DEIJ Committment</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/work_with_us">Job Opportunities</a>
                    <a class="nav-link no-border" href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/CI4/about/contact">Contact</a>
                </div>
            </li>                        
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>




that is expected.  The menus open on hover, but you can click to go to the link...

... How do you plan to do a hover on a phone ? The problem you see is because the devtool mobile view simulates a phone so you dont have hover effects, like a phone user does. Screens canot detect if you are hovering in front of the screen, they just click.

on my phone the first click is to expand the menu.  I thought this was default behavior?

At least for me in android it expanded, but got redirected to the new page. I suggest not to do hovers to display submenus, you can not detect properly if the device has tactile screen, so its a good practice to have a click for opening dropdowns, as bootstrap does by default.
Also add the dropdown-toggle to the link that has the dropdown, it will add a chevron to indicate which elements have elements inside to open and which are direct links, its a better user exp, now i don't even know where to click to test the dropdowns.
